# AWS SNS Service

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, laravel-5, amazon-sns

```
$args = array(
                "SenderID" => "SenderName",
                "AWS.SNS.SMS.SMSType" => "Transactional",
                "Message" => "Testing",
                'PhoneNumber' => '+91xxxxxxxxx',
            );
```

When I try to send sms using the extension everything works fine.

But when i remove the extension no error pops up and i dont receive the message.

```
Mobile Number = +919876543210
```

where +91 is the extension followed by the mobile number.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

That extension part you are referring to, **is mandatory**.

AWS SNS SMS follows [E.164 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.164#Numbering_formats).

you can read more [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_publish-to-phone.html)

From above link:

> When you send an SMS message, specify the phone number using the E.164
>   format. E.164 is a standard for the phone number structure used for
>   international telecommunication. Phone numbers that follow this format
>   can have a maximum of 15 digits, and they are prefixed with the plus
>   character (+) and the country code. For example, a U.S. phone number
>   in E.164 format would appear as +1XXX5550100.

HIH